# Uber jar with ehcache breaks with Swagger

Tags: reflection, swagger, ehcache, dropwizard, maven-shade-plugin

For a Dropwizard application, a Uber-jar is created using maven-shade-plugin. When I try to start it, the Bootstrap class loading done by **swagger** (dropwizard-swagger bundle) breaks trying to load the classes inside **ehcache** jar. These classes have a **custom class loader**, and are inside a folder in the jar with a different extension (.class_terracotta).
- Is there a way to tell Swagger/Reflections to use a Custom classloader so that it can resolve these classes?
- Is there a way to exclude the classes from the scanning, so that it does not attempt the loading?

Comment: you are using ehcache 2.10.3 right ? You should not include the rest api provided by the ehcache jar in your swagger documentation; this a technical monitoring and management rest api; we call it the "rest agent" - think of it as a JMX over Rest functionality.

Comment: No, it's ehcache 2.8.3, is there a jar that does not include the rest api? All I found was the ehcache jar, wich includes it.
I tried excluding the clases under the private classpath using maven-shade-plugin filters, but these are use in the non filtered code.

Comment: well, if I were you I'd rather investigate how to tell swagger to ignore those private packages and private classes. You could still use [ehcache-core](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.ehcache.internal%7Cehcache-core%7C2.8.3%7Cjar) but it's not intended to be used directly, notice the "internal" in the package name - you'll probably encounter other issues doing so.